# UISegmentedControl Text Color Issue

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using this for changing the text color of text of segmented control but its color is not getting changed in `UIControlStateNormal`. I have to kept the same color for both states.

```
NSDictionary *highlightedAttributes = [NSDictionary 
    dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
[self.segmentController
    setTitleTextAttributes:highlightedAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set any attributes explicitly for the normal state (`UIControlStateNormal`) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13],
                                 UITextAttributeTextColor: UIColorFromRGB(0x93938D),
                                 UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor clearColor]
                                 };
[self.segmentController setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.segmentController setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```